# Cannot sort a set correctly

Tags: python, sorting

```
UCI = {'A+': 4.0, 'A': 4.0,'A-': 3.7,
       'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0,'B-': 2.7,
       'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0,'C-': 1.7,
       'D+': 1.3, 'D': 1.0,'D-': 0.7,
       'F': 0.0}

def top(student_info : {(str,str)}) -> {str}:
    name_set = set()
    for x in sorted(student_info, key = lambda x: x[0][-1], reverse = True):            
        print(x)

top({('Alice','C'),('Bobby','B-'),('Carol','B-'),('David','D'),('Evelyn','C+')})
```

I want to sort this set by the key of their grade from the highest to the lowest. However, it does not give me the right order. What I got is:

```
('Bobby', 'B-')
('Evelyn', 'C+')
('Carol', 'B-')
('Alice', 'C')
('David', 'D')
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you meant `key = lambda x: UCI[x[-1]]`.

Comment: How do you figure out what the lambda x is?? I have a hard time figuring out what it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sorting correctly.  You have it sorting by the last character in the first item in the tuple.  The `key` function is going to be fed individual elements, like `('Alice', 'C')`.  So `x[0][-1]` gets the first element (`'Alice'`) and then takes the last character (`'e'`).  The output is in reverse order.

What you want is

```
lambda x: UCI[x[1]]
```

Comment: How do you figure out what the lambda x is?? I have a hard time figuring out what it is...

Comment: So, x refers to what is inside the thing before the key, which is "studnet_info"?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
>>> sorted(students, key = lambda x: UCI[x[1]], reverse=True)
[('Carol', 'B-'), ('Bobby', 'B-'), ('Evelyn', 'C+'), ('Alice', 'C'), ('David', 'D')]
```

You were never referencing UCI in your sorting.

In the lambda, `x` is the tuple (name, grade) so `x[0]` is name, and `x[1]` is the grade.  You want to sort by the numerical value of grade based on the lookup in UCI, so that would be `UCI[x[1]]`

Comment: How do you figure out what the lambda x is?? I have a hard time figuring out what it is...

Comment: The argument to the lambda is an individual element from the iterable being sorted.  If you were to sort `[{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "baz"}, {"foo": "boff"}]` then `x` would be the individual dictionaries.  If you sorted `abcdefg` then the `x` would be the individual characters.